# Detect ad block script, runs properly only on hard reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, adblock

I use this script [FuckAdBlock](https://github.com/sitexw/FuckAdBlock) to detect ad block to my website. In summary when a page loads it checks if ad block is enabled. If it is, a function is triggered in which you can notify user etc.

It works fine but there is an issue. It runs only when I hard reload the page. **On normal reload nothing happens and that's the issue.**

```
        // Function called if AdBlock is not detected
        function AdBlockNotDetected() {
            alert('AdBlock is not enabled');
        }
        //Function called if AdBlockis detected
        function AdBlockDetected() {
            alert('AdBlock Detected');
        }


        if(typeof fuckAdBlock === 'undefined') {
            AdBlockDetected();
        } else {
            fuckAdBlock.onDetected(AdBlockDetected);
            fuckAdBlock.onNotDetected(AdBlockNotDetected);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the check function on page load like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   // Manually check if AdBlock is enabled.
    fuckAdBlock.check(loop);
})
```

See: https://github.com/sitexw/FuckAdBlock#method-available

Comment: Also, so that your not running the functions twice (when hard reloading), perform a check to see if it's already been checked -  See is a variable is empty or not and then perform then check.